# Regex - Capture first 2 characters of a capturing group

Tags: regex

I want to match with one of strings: ab10, cd14, ef23, mn99
Regex: `(ab10|cd14|ef23|mn99)`
How can I capture words: ab, cd, ef, mn (first 2 characters of group $1)

Comment: Maybe you can make it more general if you don't need an exact string match `\b([a-z]{2})\d{2}\b`

Comment: what language are you using ?

Comment: What would be wrong with just using your current alternation and then taking a substring operation on `$1` to get the first 2 characters?

Comment: You can use a lookahead, `(?=(.{2}))(ab10|cd14|ef23|mn99)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a `(?=(..))` or `(?=(.{2}))` lookahead containing another capturing group at the start:

```js
(?=(..))(ab10|cd14|ef23|mn99)
(?=(.{2}))(ab10|cd14|ef23|mn99)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aDd5kS/1).

The two chars will land in Group 1 and the full found match in Group 2.

Another way to get it is via a [branch reset group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html):

```php
(?|(ab)10|(cd)14|(ef)23|(mn)99)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aDd5kS/2). The two char combinations will be in Group 1.

Comment: Thank you for your answer !